# State True or False and explain. If 2a ≡ 4b mod 8, then a ≡ 2b mod 8

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

So I have concluded that the statement is false however i'm having a hard time explaining them, or writing a proof which I need to do for full marks. Could any one help me in explaining this, please be thorough so that I could understand more of proving these types of questions.

edit: I am no longer sure than the statement is false. I have tried my example again and have realized that I made a mistake. Now I need clarification on whether it is false or not.

2nd edit: Okay my progress is that, in order for the first equation to be true a must be an even number and b must be odd, we then get a modulus of 4 for all even integers a and odd integers b. I have tried many examples and they all turn out to be true. Again i'm having a hard time explaining or proving why.

Comment: If it's false, a single counterexample is all you need.

Comment: So assigning a and b integer values would be enough of a proof?

Comment: One counterexample is all it takes to disprove a result.  If you want to add more, you can point out that $2$ hasn't got an inverse $\pmod 8$ so $2m\equiv 2n\pmod 8$ does not imply that $m\equiv n\pmod 8$.  But, really, a single counterexample already kills the theorem.

Comment: guys check edits I have come to a new conclusion, I need clarification

Comment: Your original instinct was right,  The statement is false.  Take $a=2,b=3$ for example.  The condition $2a\equiv 4b \pmod 8$ just implies that $a\equiv 2b \pmod 4$ which is weaker.

Comment: $am\equiv an \mod {b} \implies m\equiv n \mod \frac {b}{(a,b)}$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.  Consider the following counterexample.  Let $a = 6$ and $b = 9$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
2a & \equiv 12 \equiv 4 \pmod{8}\\
4b & \equiv 36 \equiv 4 \pmod{8}
\end{align*}
so $2a \equiv 4b \pmod{8}$.  However,
\begin{align*}
a & \equiv 6 \pmod{8}\\
2b & \equiv 18 \equiv 2 \pmod{8}
\end{align*}
so $a \not\equiv 2b \pmod{8}$.

Observe that if $2a \equiv 4b \pmod{8}$, then $2a = 4b + 8k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $a = 2b + 4k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, which implies that 
$a \equiv 2b \pmod{4}$.  Observe that if $a = 6$ and $b = 9$, then 
\begin{align*}
a & \equiv 2 \pmod{4}\\
2b & \equiv 18 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}
\end{align*}
so $a \equiv 2b \pmod{4}$, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks so much i understand much better now

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with going back to definitions if one has a hard time seeing it directly.

$2a \equiv 4b \mod 8 \implies$

$2a = 4b + 8k$ for some $k \implies$

$a = 2b + 4k \implies $

$a \equiv 2b \mod 4$.

Now we lost the $8$ because we divided by $2$.

This implies it doesn't have to be true because although $2a$ and $4b$ must be a multiple of $8$ apart, $a$ and $2b$ only need to be a multiple of $4$ apart.

To find a specific counter example simply let $2b - a = 4$.  Example $b= 3$ and $a = 2$.

Than $2a = 4 \equiv 4b = 12 \mod 8$.

But $a = 2\not \equiv 2b = 6 \mod 8$.

=====

Maybe clearer to see is

$2a \equiv 4b \mod 8 \iff 2a - 4b \equiv 0 \mod 8 \iff 8|2a -4b$

$a \equiv 2b \mod 8 \iff a-2b \equiv 0 \mod 8 \iff 8|a - 2b$.

So the question is... is it ever possible for $8|2a - 4b$ but not have $8|a-2b$.  And the answer to that should be easie.  $8|2a - 4b \implies 4|a - 2b$ but not that $8|a-2b$.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I got it!